# Is $\int_{\gamma} \sec ^2z \ \mathrm{d}z=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

> Let $\gamma = \gamma(0;2)$. Is
>   $$\int_{\gamma} \sec ^2z \ \mathrm{d}z$$
>   equal to $0$?

I'm trying to answer this question using only tools like Cauchy Theorem or the Deformation Theorem since contour integration is treated later in the book I took this exercise from.

So I know that

$$\sec^2z = \frac{1}{\cos^2z}$$
so the points where holomorphy might fail are the zeros of $\cos z$. So

$$\sec^2 z =0 \iff z= \frac{1}{2}(2k+1)\pi$$ 
for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now, in my path, I have two zeroes, $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$, and I don't see how creating a new path around any of those points can help me out here. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I just realized that Fundamental theorem of calculus applies here to the function $\tan z$, so the integral is indeed zero.

Comment: Can you use the residue theorem?

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm afraid I can't. But can you take a look to my edit? I think Fundamental theorem would work here.

Comment: The function isn't analytic in the int. region so you can't have a primitive function (or potential if you want) for it there.

Comment: @DonAntonio But I don't need the function to be analytic in the whole disc $D(0;2)$, right? I just need an open set containing the trace of $\gamma$ where $\tan z$ exists and that  $\sec^2 z$ is continous at each point of the trace of $\gamma$. Maybe I'm misreading the theorem or something.

Comment: Nop. You need the function to be analytin on the path *and* within the enclosed region to apply it, **but** what you can do here is to take two little circles around both singularities of $\;\cot z\;$ and etc. Yet I can't see something like that proposed in your question...unless that's what you had in mind when you wrote that about "a new path" ...

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, I've seen some exercises that use Deformation theorem when there is a singularity in the interior of $\gamma$, so the integral around a little circle with the singularity as the center of it equals the integral along the original path. But in this case there are two singularities and I don't know how it applies there. Should the integral along $\gamma$ be the sum of the integrals along two little circles around the singularities?

Comment: I think using power series it can be seen the apportations of each integral around each singularity cancel with each other and the outcome is zero, but I'm not sure...and I'm not sure either whether you can use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you allowed to use path\line integrals?

If yes, then just write the parametrization for $\gamma$: $\gamma(t) = 2 \exp(it).$

Now,
$$
\int_\gamma \sec^2(z) \, \rm{d} z = \int_0^{2\pi} \sec^2(2 \exp(it)) \cdot  2i \exp(it) \, \rm{d} t = \left. \tan(2 \exp(it)) \right|_{t=0}^{2\pi} = 0.
$$

I guess that what you mean by the Fundamental theorem of calculus (you don't need any complex analysis).

Comment: I am allowed to use path integrals, and it must be me being a little slowly today, but what happens when $t=\pi /2$? Shouldn't there be a problem as well?

Comment: It just reminds me to the argument: $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\cos^2 x} dx = \tan(2\pi)-\tan(0) =0$, but the integral doesn't converge.

Comment: You are integrating in the complex plane. The function $\sec(z)$ only has singularities at $\pm \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi k$, and none of these points are on the circle $|z|=2$, so the function is continuous there.

Comment: Ahh, okay, so I don't need the function to be holomorphic in the interior of the path, just continous in it?

Comment: Yes, you just use the definition of a path integral. The function $\tan(z)$ is the meromorphic anti-derivative of $\sec^2(z)$.

Comment: Ah, got it! And is there by any chance a way to solve it using the Deformation Theorem? (I'm only asking this because that was one of the topics discussed in the chapter where this exercise comes from).

Comment: I don't see any direct way to use it. Maybe one of the topics of the chapter is anti-derivatives?